# Springboot 3.2.2 and CRaC failure in Docker but work in WSL

Tags: spring-boot, crac

Good day community.
I tried to run my application from checkpoint in Windows WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 and this worked well.
But in Docker with the same Ubuntu and Zulu JDK version it fails.

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
COPY zulu21.tar.gz /opt/
RUN tar -xzf /opt/zulu21.tar.gz -C /opt
ENV JAVA_HOME /opt/zulu21.32.17-ca-crac-jdk21.0.2-linux_x64
ENV PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
RUN chown root:root $JAVA_HOME/lib/criu
RUN chmod u+s $JAVA_HOME/lib/criu
...
```

docker run --privileged {image_name}

Errors

```
2024-01-26 15:10:26 An exception during a checkpoint operation:
2024-01-26 15:10:26 jdk.internal.crac.mirror.CheckpointException
2024-01-26 15:10:26     Suppressed: jdk.internal.crac.mirror.impl.CheckpointOpenResourceException: FD fd=17 type=unknown path=anon_inode:[eventpoll]
2024-01-26 15:10:26             at java.base/jdk.internal.crac.mirror.Core.translateJVMExceptions(Core.java:117)
2024-01-26 15:10:26             at java.base/jdk.internal.crac.mirror.Core.checkpointRestore1(Core.java:188)
2024-01-26 15:10:26             at java.base/jdk.internal.crac.mirror.Core.checkpointRestore(Core.java:286)
2024-01-26 15:10:26             at java.base/jdk.internal.crac.mirror.Core.checkpointRestoreInternal(Core.java:299)
2024-01-26 15:10:26     Suppressed: jdk.internal.crac.mirror.impl.CheckpointOpenResourceException: FD fd=18 type=unknown path=anon_inode:[eventfd]
2024-01-26 15:10:26             at java.base/jdk.internal.crac.mirror.Core.translateJVMExceptions(Core.java:117)
2024-01-26 15:10:26             at java.base/jdk.internal.crac.mirror.Core.checkpointRestore1(Core.java:188)
2024-01-26 15:10:26             at java.base/jdk.internal.crac.mirror.Core.checkpointRestore(Core.java:286)
2024-01-26 15:10:26             at java.base/jdk.internal.crac.mirror.Core.checkpointRestoreInternal(Core.java:299)
2024-01-26 15:10:26     Suppressed: jdk.internal.crac.mirror.impl.CheckpointOpenResourceException: FD fd=19 type=unknown path=anon_inode:[timerfd]
2024-01-26 15:10:26             at java.base/jdk.internal.crac.mirror.Core.translateJVMExceptions(Core.java:117)
2024-01-26 15:10:26             at java.base/jdk.internal.crac.mirror.Core.checkpointRestore1(Core.java:188)
2024-01-26 15:10:26             at java.base/jdk.internal.crac.mirror.Core.checkpointRestore(Core.java:286)
2024-01-26 15:10:26             at java.base/jdk.internal.crac.mirror.Core.checkpointRestoreInternal(Core.java:299)
2024-01-26 15:10:26     Suppressed: jdk.internal.crac.mirror.impl.CheckpointOpenResourceException: FD fd=20 type=unknown path=anon_inode:[eventpoll]
2024-01-26 15:10:26             at java.base/jdk.internal.crac.mirror.Core.translateJVMExceptions(Core.java:117)
2024-01-26 15:10:26             at java.base/jdk.internal.crac.mirror.Core.checkpointRestore1(Core.java:188)
2024-01-26 15:10:26             at java.base/jdk.internal.crac.mirror.Core.checkpointRestore(Core.java:286)
```

I tried on my local Docker and in AWS EC2. The exceptions are the same.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some investigation I discovered that the problem was in grpc/netty. I rescheduled the launch of the grpc client after recovery. Looks fine so far

Comment: I have the same issue but with gRPC/Netty server. Where can I check your workaround? My question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78214270/how-should-i-handle-the-grpc-server-shutdown-during-crac-checkpointing